# get html file content in wordpress template standards

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I'm trying to get html file content in wordpress admin side, and I've tried simply `file_get_contents` but it doesn't works correctly in some wordpress versions. Then I found `wp_remote_get` function; this one works correctly but `wp_debuger` noticed error:

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

So how do I simply give html file content to variable? 
Thanks in advance.

I have tried:

```
$template=wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get(get_template_directory_uri().'/‌​admin/templates/settings.htm'));
```

Comment: It is `file_get_contents` and not `file_get_content`

Comment: c'mon guys is  there any wordpress developer ??

Comment: i have tried 
`$template=wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get(get_template_directory_uri().'/admin/templates/settings.htm'));`

Answer (score 0):

**Filesystem API**: The Filesystem API abstracts out the functionality needed for reading and writing local files to the filesystem to be done securely, on a variety of host types.

Check references: [Filesystem API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API)